# Question on Flows generated by smooth vector fields on a smooth manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given a smooth vector field $V$ on a smooth manifold $M$, $\exists$ $!$ smooth maximal flow $\theta: D \rightarrow M$ generated by $V$ such that:

a) For each $p \in M$, the curve $\theta^{(p)}: D^{(p)} \rightarrow M$ is the unique maximal integral curve of $V$ starting at $p$.

b) If $s \in D^{(p)}$, then $D^{(\theta(s,p))}$ is the interval $D^{(p)}-s = \{t-s : t \in D^{(p)} \}$

c) $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $M_t$ is open in $M$ and $\theta_t: M_t \rightarrow M_{-t}$ is a diffeomorphism with inverse $\theta_{-t}$

---

Here, $D$ is the flow domain of the flow and $M_t = \{ p \in M : (t,p) \in D \}$

So, $M_t$ is every value of $t$, which we can think of as time, where the integral curve starting at $p$ is defined after moving along for $t$.

I'm wondering, what is the geometric significance that $M_t \cong M_{-t}$??

$\theta_t: M_t \rightarrow M_{-t}$ is defined by $\theta_t(p) = \theta^{(p)}(t) = \theta(t,p)$.

Comment: Isn't a symmetric time interval part of the definition of $D$?

Comment: It wasn't part of the definition of the flow domain, which states that $\forall p \in M$ the set $D^{(p)} = \{t \in \mathbb{R} : (t,p) \in D\}$ is an open interval containing zero. 

That is just the definition of a flow domain, perhaps there is a reason that with a maximal flow domain the time intervals will now be symmetric? I don't understand why this should be though, if we look at the plane without an origin and then look at the flow generated by the infinitesimal generator $\frac{d}{dx}$, then it seems the point $(-.001,0)$ will not have a symmetric flow domain??

Comment: The original statement looks suspect to me. Can you double-check all hypotheses and details? And how does $\theta_t$ map $M_t$ to $M_{-t}$?

Comment: I've edited the statement, there were no errors, but I added conditions $(a)$ and $(b)$ for the sake of completeness, and an explicit definition of $\theta_t$.

This is from page 212 second edition of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of $M_t$ is wrong. It's the set of all points in $M$ from which you *can* flow for time $t$. The point then is that if $p\in M_t$, then $\theta_t(p)\in M_{-t}$ because you can flow backwards from $\theta_t(p)$ for time $t$ and get back to $p$. The mapping is a diffeomorphism, as Lee says, because you can go "backwards" from $M_{-t}$ to $M_t$ by the flow $\theta_{-t}$.